# Tricky :: re-write a function to be tail-recursive

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I have this scala function, that, because of performance problems, needs to be rewritten to be tail-recursive. The stack blows off when processing a not-so-big dataset, therefore I conclude it can be fixed only by making it tail-recursive.
This is the function ::

```
private def carve2(x: Int, y: Int) {

    var rand: Int = random.nextInt(4)

    (1 to 4) foreach { _ =>
        val (x1, y1, x2, y2) = randomize(x, y, rand)

        if (canUpdate(x1, y1, x2, y2)) {
           maze(y1)(x1) = 0
           maze(y2)(x2) = 0
           carve2(x2, y2)
       }
       rand = (rand + 1) % 4
    }

}
```

The main problem is ::

```
> How to get rid of the foreach/for loop
```

For this I tried a recursive approach, but it is tricky to get the semantics right, especially because, after self-call inside the if block, the value of the rand var is mutated...

What I tried is to push the state modification of rand out of the body, and mutate it when passed as parameter::

```
def carve3(x: Int, y: Int, rand: Int)  {

  for (i <- 1 to 4) {

    val (x1, y1, x2, y2) = randomize(x, y, rand)

    if (canUpdate(x1, y1, x2, y2)) {
       maze(y1)(x1) = 0
       maze(y2)(x2) = 0
      if (i == 1) carve3(x2, y2, random.nextInt(4))
      else carve3(x2, y2, (rand + 1) % 4)
    }
 }
}
```

This does not work...

One more thing, I know this coding approach is not functional, but I am trying to get there...this is code I try to re-factor.
Also, randomize and canUpdate functions are not relevant in this context.

Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming there that your profiler has identified this as a hotspot :)

Your problem, as you correctly infer, is the for-comprehension which adds an extra level of indirection for each time through the loop.  The cost of this will be negligible for just 4 passes, but I can see that the method calls itself recursively...

What I *wouldn't* do is start by attempting to refactor to use tail-recursion, you have two better options you can try first:

1. Change the `foreach` to a for-comprehension then compile with the `optimize` flag, this should cause the compiler to emit a `while` loop.
2. If that doesn't help, convert the comprehension to a `while` loop by hand.

Then... and only then, you might want to try tail recursion to see if it's faster than the while loop.  Chances are that it won't be.

**UPDATE**

I was heading towards Petr's solution anyway :)

So here's the full thing tidied up to be a bit more idiomatic:

```
private def carve2(x: Int, y: Int) {
  carve2(List((x, y)))
}

@tailrec private def carve2(coords: List[(Int,Int)]) = coords match {
  case (x,y) :: rest =>
    val rand: Int = random.nextInt(4)

    //note that this won't necessarily yield four pairs of co-ords
    //due to the guard condition
    val add = for {
      i <- 1 to 4
      (x1, y1, x2, y2) = randomize(x, y, (i + rand) % 4)
      if canUpdate(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    } yield {
      maze(y1)(x1) = 0
      maze(y2)(x2) = 0
      (x2, y2)
    }

    // tail recursion happens here...
    carve2(rest ++ add)

  case _ => 
}
```

Comment: With four recursive calls, would it really help to make it tail recursive?

Comment: No... but the recursion here means that it's potentially a *lot* more than 4 times

Comment: Oh no, I realise that the actual number of calls *total* is more than 4, I'm suggesting that a tail recursion optimisation would only remove one of the 3 calls, and the others would have to be managed in a stack anyway. I suppose it's worth checking but I figured conversion to a tail recursion won't do much.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I'll try your suggestion. As for the problem that I encountered -- the stack blows off when processing a not-so-big dataset, therefore I concluded it can be fixed only by making it tail-recursive...I'll edit my post.

Comment: Okay, that's a different problem.  I'll update the answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 4):

If a function calls itself multiple times, it can't be converted to a tail-recursive one. A function can be tail recursive only if the recursive call is the last thing it does, so that it doesn't need to remember anything.

A standard trick for solving this kind of problem is to use the heap instead of the stack by keeping the tasks to be computed in a queue. For example:

```
private def carve2(x: Int, y: Int) {
    carve2(Seq((x, y)));
}

@annotation.tailrec
private def carve2(coords: Seq[(Int,Int)]) {
    // pick a pair of coordinates
    val ((x, y), rest) = coords match {
      case Seq(x, xs@_*) => (x, xs);
      case _             => return; // empty
    }
    // This is functional approach, although perhaps slower.
    // Using a `while` loop instead would result in faster code.
    val rand: Int = random.nextInt(4)
    val add: Seq[(Int,Int)] =
      for(i <- 1 to 4;
          (x1, y1, x2, y2) = randomize(x, y, (i + rand) % 4);
          if (canUpdate(x1, y1, x2, y2))
         ) yield {
        // do something with `maze`
        // ...
        // return the new coordinates to be added to the queue
        (x2, y2)
      }
    // the tail-recursive call
    carve2(rest ++ add);
}
```

(I haven't tried to compile the code as the code sample you posted isn't self-contained.)

Here `carve2` runs in a tail-recursive loop. Each pass possibly adds new coordinates to the end of the queue, and finishes when the queue is empty.

Comment: Thanks Petr! I'll try your approach asap :-)